# What voxel format is used by blender to store smoke data?

Tags: export, smoke-simulation, baking

What voxel format is used by blender for storing smoke data? There is an easy way to export this data to something like OpenVDB? It's for use the simulation in our current rendering engine (Guerilla Render) that support openVDB format. Or is it an easy format to get the voxel back into Guerilla Render.

Answer (score 1):

When baking smoke Blender can save the cache as OpenVDB.  Select the smoke domain, go to the physics panel, and go into the smoke cache settings.  Change the file format from "Point Cache" to "OpenVDB".  You can then choose your compression and data depth.